# How to update a single library with Composer?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I need to install only 1 package for my SF2 distribution (DoctrineFixtures).

When I run

```
php composer.phar update
```

I get

```
  - Updating twig/twig (dev-master 39d94fa => v1.13.0)
    The package has modified files:
    M CHANGELOG
    M doc/filters/batch.test
    M doc/filters/index.rst
    M doc/filters/url_encode.rst
    M doc/functions/index.rst
    M doc/tags/index.rst
    M doc/tests/index.rst
    M lib/Twig/Autoloader.php
    M lib/Twig/Compiler.php
    M lib/Twig/CompilerInterface.php
-10 more files modified, choose "v" to view the full list
```

It appears the last developer edited a lot of files inside vendor.

In order to get around this, I tried

```
php composer.phar update <package_name>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. How can I update/install only one library from composer.json?

Comment: Your are using the right command. Can you show us your `composer.json`?

Comment: please try with the commands provided in my answer otherwise please provide a description of the error you get ( i.e. composer output if composer is complaining )

Comment: Your composer.json might refer to an alternate fork of a project.

Comment: I updated a specific dependency in my laravel project and specifying the specific component to install explicitly: composer update laravelcollective/html. That seemed to work.

Comment: "But that doesn't seem to work" why do you think so?

Answer (score 743, accepted):

To install `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle` with version `2.1.*` and minimum stability `@dev` use this:

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle:2.1.*@dev
```

then to update only this single package:

```
composer update doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
```

Comment: May be helpful: running update/install with -vvv (verbose mode: composer.phar update -vvv package/package) can sometimes be better as occasionally an interactive prompt will appear which may be otherwise hidden

Comment: always update optimizing ClassMap. "composer update -o" , add "-o" parameter

Comment: What's the use of the `update` command in this example ? Doesn't the `require` already update/install the package ? When I `update` immediatly after `require`, composer says "Nothing to install or update".

Comment: `update` appears to do nothing at all. It does *not* upgrade my package to the latest version as specified by my constraint in composer.json.

Comment: > composer.phar update doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle

this updates all other packages too (((

Comment: i get the following message
Package "abc/pqr:1.0.5" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information

Comment: Does not work, this updates many packages

Comment: It's worth pointing out that although this updates the specific package as requested - if your composer.lock file has anything set to be removed - these will get uninstalled! :(

Answer (score 244):

If you just want to update a few packages and not all, you can list them as such:

```
php composer.phar update vendor/package:2.* vendor/package2:dev-master
```

You can also use wildcards to update a bunch of packages at once:

```
php composer.phar update vendor/*
```

As commented by [@ZeroThe2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4327948/zerothe2nd) ZSH users may need to wrap their vendor/* in quotation marks:

```
php composer.phar update "vendor/*"
```

- **--prefer-source**: Install packages from `source` when available.
- **--prefer-dist**: Install packages from `dist` when available.
- **--ignore-platform-reqs**: ignore `php`, `hhvm`, `lib-*` and `ext-*` requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these. See also the `platform` [config option](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#config).
- **--dry-run**: Simulate the command without actually doing anything.
- **--dev**: Install packages listed in `require-dev` (this is the default behavior).
- **--no-dev**: Skip installing packages listed in `require-dev`. The autoloader generation skips the `autoload-dev` rules.
- **--no-autoloader**: Skips autoloader generation.
- **--no-scripts**: Skips execution of scripts defined in composer.json.
- **--no-plugins**: Disables plugins.
- **--no-progress**: Removes the progress display that can mess with some terminals or scripts which don't handle backspace characters.
- **--optimize-autoloader (-o)**: Convert PSR-0/4 autoloading to classmap to get a faster autoloader. This is recommended especially for production, but can take a bit of time to run so it is currently not done by default.
- **--lock**: Only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date.
- **--with-dependencies**: Add also all dependencies of whitelisted packages to the whitelist.
- **--prefer-stable**: Prefer stable versions of dependencies.
- **--prefer-lowest**: Prefer lowest versions of dependencies. Useful for testing minimal versions of requirements, generally used with `--prefer-stable`.

Comment: Please note that ZSH users may need to wrap their `vendor/*` in quotation marks: `composer update "vendor/*"`

Answer (score 165):

### Difference between install, update and require

Assume the following scenario:

***composer.json***

```
"parsecsv/php-parsecsv": "0.*"
```

***composer.lock file***

```
  "name": "parsecsv/php-parsecsv",
            "version": "0.1.4",
```

> Latest release is `1.1.0`. The latest `0.*` release is `0.3.2`

**install:**    `composer install parsecsv/php-parsecsv`

This will install version `0.1.4` as specified in the lock file

**update:** `composer update parsecsv/php-parsecsv`

This will update the package to `0.3.2`. The highest version with respect to your composer.json. The entry in `composer.lock` will be updated.

**require:** `composer require parsecsv/php-parsecsv`

This will update or install the newest version `1.1.0`. Your `composer.lock` file and `composer.json` file will be updated as well.

Comment: awesome, so to refresh one package within the constrained version it's `composer update author/package` and then `composer install author/package`

Comment: @WilliamRandokun if you have installed it before, then just `composer update package` is enough, no need to call install after it

Comment: exactly what I am looking for. well explained. `upvoted`

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted answer as it highlights the upgrade constrains both from `composer.json` and `composer.lock`

Comment: tnx. I never knew that `composer require` updates also the package to latest version.

Comment: I think this is out of date. It seems to update all packages and did not touch my composer.json file at all.

Comment: @tremby no, this is still how composer works. If you run `composer update` it will update all packages, if you run `composer update package` it will just update package. If `composer.json` does not change, it means everything was already up-to-date.

Comment: @Adam I looked back in my shell history. `composer update nystudio107/craft-retour` led to 0 installs, 41 updates (including many totally unrelated packages), 0 removals, and the only changed file tracked by git was composer.lock. But: it's likely my vendor directory was not in sync with composer.lock to start with, which would explain it.

Comment: And no, I don't think "if composer.json does not change, it means everything was already up-to-date" is correct. For me it updated the package I asked for but it did not change composer.json. The new version was still within the range composer.json specified, but was certainly updated.

Comment: @tremby I tried to create a case locally for me, where vendor was not in sync with composer.lock. When I update a single library, then I get first only one update for the package: `Updating dependencies                                 
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
` and after that all other packages in the vendor folder seem to be updated that are out of place `Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 57 updates, 0 removals
`

Comment: So for a clean setup, maybe remove your vendor folder and install it using `composer install`. Then update package X will just update the single package.

Comment: And the second thing. I meant the `composer.lock`. So assuming your vendor folder aligns with `composer.lock`, and after a paclage update `composer.lock` is not changed, then no update took place.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the following command to update any module with its dependencies

```
composer update vendor-name/module-name --with-dependencies
```

Answer (score 19):

You can basically do following one to install new package as well.

```
php composer.phar require
```

then terminal will ask you to enter the name of the package for searching.

```
$ Search for a package []: //Your package name here
```

Then terminal will ask the version of the package (If you would like to have the latest version just leave it blank)

```
$ Enter the version constraint to require (or leave blank to use the latest version) []: //your version number here
```

Then you just press the return key. Terminal will ask for another package, if you dont want to install another one just press the return key and you will be done.

Answer (score 15):

Just use

```
composer require {package/packagename}
```

like

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

if the package is not in the vendor folder.. composer installs it and if the package exists, composer update package to the latest version.

**Update**:

`require` install or update the latest package version. if you want update one package just use `update`.

Comment: That won't work as expected, as it would put the library into `composer.json`. This is not needed for updating a package

Comment: Does not work as expected. It also updates / downgrades other packages in the process.

Comment: @Black `require` install or update the latest package version. if you wanna update one package just use `update`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

To ensure that composer update one package already installed to the last version within the version constraints you've set in composer.json remove the package from vendor and then execute :

```
php composer.phar update vendor/package
```

Comment: You will find the same suggestion in this post : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3112.

PS: Down vote without explanation is so easy to do and so useless.

Answer (score 5):

Because you wanted to install specific package
"I need to install only 1 package for my SF2 distribution (DoctrineFixtures)."

`php composer.phar require package/package-name:package-version`
would be enough