# Why composer does not update specific package?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I want to update voyager package from `1.2` to `1.3` for that I changed

`"tcg/voyager": "1.3.*"` 
and then executed command `composer update tcg/voyager --lock`
but it does not update, I just want to update voyager.
[image]

Can someone kindly guide me how can I update it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Why are you using `--lock` ?

Comment: There is a possibility of `tcg/voyager[v1.2.7]` being requested specifically by some other package's dependency

Comment: @apokryfos not sure, I am following this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175861/composer-laravel-how-to-add-update-a-specific-package?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Can you show us your `composer.json` file

Comment: If you updated version from `1.2` to `1.3` in `composer.json` file, just run `composer update` command, don't update `composer.lock` file. It'll update lock file itself!