# Composer doesn't install latest Laravel (5.0.15)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Latest stable version of Laravel is 5.0.15 but when I run

`composer install laravel/laravel` :

It says:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.1)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.1)
    Downloading: 100%
```

I've run `composer clear-cache` but same version is downloaded.

How can I force composer to install latest stable version.

Contents of composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
},
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ca3d46d702541965dfc

Comment: Add the contents of your `composer.json`

Comment: v5.0.1 seems to be the latest. https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel

Comment: @tlenss Oh, but why does it say `stable:5.0.15` on it's github home?! https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Comment: it now says 5.0.16 now

Comment: Where do you see that? Because the latest tag is 5.0.1. And the tags are what triggers packagist to pull a package.

Comment: hes talking about the little graphic in readme.md

Comment: Thanks @cmorrissey . My bad.. they have `laravel/laravel` and `laravel/framework`

Comment: So the install command you run is different from the package defined in your composer.json

Comment: I've found out what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
composer install laravel/framework
```

Comment: Good job. But let my answer go up for someone who needs more details!

Comment: @tlenss would `composer update laravel/framework` be more smarter to use, because then you would automatically use composer.json? See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739998/symfony2-how-to-update-a-single-library-with-composer-phar

Comment: You are absolutely correct about that. I was just correcting the OP's command.

Answer (score 2):

It's because there is a `laravel/laravel` which is the main package and another package `laravel/framework` which is one of the dependencies of the main package.

the latest `laravel/laravel` is `5.0.1` and the latest `laravel/framework` is `5.0.15`.

So while installing packages if it says:

```
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.0.16)
```

It means that you'r getting the latest version.

Comment: So you use other peoples comments to answer your own question. o well!

Comment: @tlenss Haha, no, before you posting your comment (My bad..) I was checking https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/framework and found it out! Kind of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_discovery !!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `composer update laravel/framework`, because then you would automatically use the requirements in your composer.json file.

That is if you already installed a laravel/framework package.

See, [How to update a single library with Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739998/symfony2-how-to-update-a-single-library-with-composer-phar)