# How to install 2 Symfony bundles at the same time with composer which depend on each other

Tags: symfony, composer-php, elastica, foselasticabundle

I want to upgrade `friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle` from `3.1.*` to `dev-master`.

You can see bellow my current composer.json setting:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    ...
     "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.1.*"
},
```

The problem is when I remove the row `friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle` and then run `composer require fiendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle "dev-master"` :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- Installation request for friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle[dev-master].
- friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle dev-master requires ruflin/elastica 3.2.* -> satisfiable by ruflin/elastica[3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Then I run `composer require ruflin/elastica "3.2.*"` and got this :
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
- The requested package friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle (locked at 3.1.8, required as dev-master) is satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle[3.1.8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

So my problem is that I need to install `ruflin/elastica` in order to upgrade `friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle` but I also need to upgrade `friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle` to install `ruflin/elastica`

How can I manage to do it properly ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer of @Purple Hexagon is correct, other way to do it is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739998/how-to-update-a-single-library-with-composer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think there is really a time you would need to remove the older version from your composer.json before running a require. But to answer your question ... You have two options the way I see it.

1: try and install both new packages in one command

```
composer require ruflin/elastica:3.2.* friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle:dev-master
```

2: just manually edit your composer.json and then run composer update

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.3.9",
  "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
  "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
  "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
  ...
   "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "dev-master",
   "ruflin/elastica": "3.2.*"

},
```

Comment: Thank you, 2nd method works like a charm, I don't know why I did not do it before.