# Upgrade Twig 1.x.x to Twig 3.x.x

Tags: symfony, twig, composer-php, twig-extension

I'm trying to upgrade Twig `1.13.2-DEV` to `3.x` but don't know how to do that as on their 
[Website](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/) not clearly mentioned and they suggest to ask question on StackOverflow :)

I used Twig only with Symfony framework not with Custom PHP website, Right now I can see two directories in server

1. Twig
2. Twig-extensions

And inside `/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php` it display me the version

`const VERSION = '1.13.2-DEV';`

Can someone have idea how to upgrade Twig?

My project is not using composer.json but inside Twig folder I have this compsoer.json

`"name": "twig/twig",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP",
    "keywords": ["templating"],
    "homepage": "http://twig.sensiolabs.org",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Fabien Potencier",
            "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Armin Ronacher",
            "email": "armin.ronacher@active-4.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
            "Twig_" : "lib/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.13-dev"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Please add the content of your `composer.json` to your question. And about composer not being installed: please look how to install it, there are many questions about this. Never ask two questions in the same post.

Comment: Thanks now only looking for twig upgrade

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a single library with Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739998/how-to-update-a-single-library-with-composer)

Comment: No this is not the answer of my question, I am seeking info to upgrade twig, not seeking for install one pakcage using compers :)

Comment: But Twig is a single library and you are using composer, aren't you? And as I said: please share your `composer.json`

Comment: No my project is not using composer.json but inside Twig folder I have composer.js file, I have updated code.