# Why "composer.json" is not updated when updating packages?

Tags: php, composer-php, updates, package-managers

Comparing to other package managers like `npm`, I find that `composer` has a strange behaviour when updating packages related to a given project.

According also to the documentation, `update` and `upgrade` options

> Upgrades your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.

And indeed, `composer.lock` is correctly updated with new packages version numbers. But `composer.json` instead is not modified, and lists packages with their old, outdated version numbers.

Why does this happen? Am I doing something wrong, or this is indeed how this is supposed to work? And if this is the case, what is the reasoning behind having one of thw two files up-to-date while the other is not?

Comment: fyi, `npm` uses `package-lock.json`

Comment: @kerbholz yes, I know, but `package.json` is updated as well when updating packages.

Comment: Are you expecting the versions specified in composer.json to be updated to the latest version when you run `composer update`? If I've specified that I want version `2.1.1` of a package, I don't want this to be changed when version `2.1.2` comes, if I did I would have written `2.1.*` or just `*`

Comment: My `composer.json` has `"package": "^4.2"` that was automatically added by `composer require`, if I run `composer update` the package is updated from version `4.2.0` to `4.3.0` and `composer.lock` is updated to this new version, but `composer.json` still lists `4.2`. My question is about this difference.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739998/how-to-update-a-single-library-with-composer/54197074#54197074 answers your question

Answer (score 9):

That's the normal behavior.

Composer update looks for updates based on your composer.json file, so here it will look for 4.2 and above (^4.2)
If you want your composer.json to require 4.3 and above (^4.3), you can either modify it manually or call composer require once again.