# Command to update only a single package via composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, vendor, recurly

We have a third party API (Recurly) installed in our site. That site was built with Laravel. The version of that API is now outdated and I want to update the version via composer.

From the Recurly I have got the following instruction to upgrade the version

**In composer.json file update the line of code from "recurly/recurly-client": "2.8." to "recurly/recurly-client": "2.12. . And this will upgrade your client library AND your API version. Once you do this, please run a composer update in your terminal->active directory w/ Recurly and it will update you:**

Now I have seen many suggestion not to run composer update command in live production server.

But Can I run the composer update only for single package. for an example

«composer update recurly/recurly-client»

If so in that case can you please suggest me what will be the command. I have not found the exact command to run the composer update only to update one single library

Our application built on laravel. This is the screenshot of our main folder structure

[image]

composer.json file and composer.lock files are under this folder  /home/alphacyrus/

And I can see recurly and recurly client folder under vendor folder. inside /home/alphacyrus/
So it is like /home/alphacyrus/vendor/recurly/recurly-client

[image]

We have cpanel Terminal option.

[image]

**What is the command to update the single package (recurly) via composer**

I have seen the link this question is associated to. I have read it. But I still have some confusion as i am not experienced. So for my case will the command be

```
composer.phar update recurly/recurly-client
```

or

```
composer update recurly/recurly-client
```

or something else

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739998/how-to-update-a-single-library-with-composer

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have read it. But I still have some confusion as i am not experienced. So for my case will the command be "composer.phar update recurly/recurly-client" or "composer update recurly/recurly-client" or something else

Comment: both are same though use composer update